# wants subcategory from category in laravel 5.2,

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

```
@foreach($category as $key => $category)
                        <select name="category" id="{{$key}}">
                            <option value="{{$key}}">{!! $category !!}</option>
                        </select>
                    @endforeach
                    <select name="subcat" id="subcategory"></select>
<script>
    $('#{{$key}}').on('click', function () {
        var id = $('#{{$key}}').val();
        $.getJSON("subcategory/" + id, function (data) {
            var subcat = $('#subcategory').empty();
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $('#subcategory').append(
                        $('<option/>').val(key).text(value)
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

how to assign laravel control id in javascript? .it work fine if i provide simple html control id in java script

Comment: your question is not clear, what do you mean by laravel control id ??

Comment: its mistake, its a id of select field. value assign  to id={{$key}} , now that id i want ro use in javascript.  i am not sure, it uses as   $('#{{$key}}').on('click', function ().  Please suggest

Comment: till not clear, are your given script is not working? Or you want to use $key variable another place in another script ? if second one then please provide what are you trying. The given one will not work for every key only for last one will. I am giving an work around for your given script.

Comment: I hope you do not want a select box for every category.

Comment: @Atiqur i want select for catagory. and want to use {{$key}} variable in java script for id purpose.   as per your answer, its working fine one select box for all category. but i want select box per category is it possible?

Comment: yes possible, I am updating the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($category as $key => $category)
    <select name="category" id="{{$key}}">
        <option value="{{$key}}">{!! $category !!}</option>
    </select>
@endforeach
```

this makes no sense for 20 category it will create 20 select box with on option!!!. I hope you  want something like this :

```
<select name="category" id="whatever" onchange="pullASubCategory(this.value)">
    @foreach($category as $key => $category)
        <option value="{{$key}}">{!! $category !!}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<select name="subcat" id="subcategory"></select>



<script>

    function pullASubCategory(categoryId){

        //I do not test this code just copied fro you....
        $.getJSON("subcategory/" + categoryId, function (data) {
            var subcat = $('#subcategory').empty();
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $('#subcategory').append(
                        $('<option/>').val(key).text(value)
                );
            });
        });
    }   

</script>
```

**Update**

```
@foreach($category as $key => $category)
    <select name="category" id="{{$key}}" onclick="pullASubCategory({{$key}})">
        <option value="{{$key}}">{!! $category !!}</option>
    </select>
@endforeach
<select name="subcat" id="subcategory"></select>

<script>

    function pullASubCategory(categoryId){

        //I do not test this code just copied fro you....
        $.getJSON("subcategory/" + categoryId, function (data) {
            var subcat = $('#subcategory').empty();
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $('#subcategory').append(
                        $('<option/>').val(key).text(value)
                );
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

you can use other event like onfocus, onselect if you want.